# Should packages be organized based on ontology/semantics of underlying classes or their functionality

Tags: java, package

Suppose I am writing an application for simulating vehicles of all types. Should I now organize packages based on the different type of vehicles e.g.,

```
com.example.vehiclesimulation.car
com.example.vehiclesimulation.truck
com.example.vehiclesimulation.bus
com.example.vehiclesimulation.motorcycle
```

or should they be organized in a structure based on the functionality e.g.,

```
com.example.vehiclesimulation.transmission
com.example.vehiclesimulation.interior
com.example.vehiclesimulation.steering
com.example.vehiclesimulation.electronics
```

Often package structures get complex as we move deeper into the structure one is clueless whether to form a subpackage or a sibling. In the above case, we could have the ontological packages as parents and then have all the functional ones as their children, and vice versa. So which one is more appropriate and why?

EDIT: It may be noted that this distinction becomes more complicated when there are deeper levels and at each level one has to choose betwen the two axes. Fo instance, should the class XYZHeadlight go under c.e.vehiclesimulation.car.XYZ.electronics or c.e.vehiclesimulation.electronics.car.XYZ or c.e.vehiclesimulation.car.electronics.XYZ?

Comment: Whatever works.  In part packages are simply a way to keep together code that you maintain together and want to manage as a single piece in JARs, etc.  The only real functional issue is that classes in a package have access to `package` scope methods and fields, which can be used to manage "encapsulation".

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the type of package. Your example in not really a good one. I would advice structuring based on functionality, but rewrite the example as follows:

```
com.example.vehicles.car
com.example.vehicles.truck
com.example.vehicles.bus
com.example.vehicles.motorcycle
```

but the following "things" are not vehicles - they are *parts* that can be used in vehicles:

```
com.example.vehicleparts.transmission
com.example.vehicleparts.interior
com.example.vehicleparts.steering
com.example.vehicleparts.electronics
```

and now in your `car` you can use `com.example.vehicleparts.transmission`.

However sometimes you might want to use `package` private fields and method, in that case you could put them all in one package to deal with it.

Comment: I meant to use com.example.vehicle (or c.e.vehiclesimulation referring to the app) and not vehicles(referring to the actual types).
Corrected!  It is not as simple as you pointed out. Your solution just shifted the problem one level up the hierarchy, assuming that any car will accept many transmission or interior types which is not true. Often classes have clear hierarchy on both ontological and functional axes. e.g., should the class XYZHeadlight go under c.e.vehiclesimulation.car.XYZ.electronics or c.e.vehiclesimulation.electronics.car.XYZ or c.e.vehiclesimulation.car.electronics.XYZ?

Comment: Okay in that case I would do it as `com.example.appname.vehicles` and `com.example.appname.vehicleparts`. And yes I assume that in `transmission` object will be used in `car`, `truck` and `motorcycle` objects. If you have a class that will be used **only** in car XYZ as `vehiclesimulation.car.XYZ` then I would make it a nested class. Whereas `c.e.vehiclesimulation.electronics.car` can be considered electronics used to be in cars. To make usable in XYZ I would suggest implementing an interface.

Comment: But I think you now see there's not a single correct solution, but if you're the only developer on the project then make sure it makes sense to YOU. Considering OOP you should try and divide the object (f.e. car) into smaller parts - wheels,engine.. Then it would make sence putting these thing in the package "car" - BUT - can't wheels be used somewhere else besides car? Then putting it there wouldn't make sense right? And we are back to start..

Answer (score 0):

I would structure them based on their functionality. The only reason I got for this is to be able to "share" components between different vehicle types, e.g. a transmission of a truck that is also used on a bus could be better placed in the second (functionality-ontological) structure, I guess. Nevertheless, it feels to me like it's just a matter of taste.